# VS2010 Database Project with Multiple Deployments

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, msdeploy, database-project

I have a database project in my vs2010 solution. The working database is installed locally on my machine. I'm wondering if there is a way to setup the project so that it can deploy to multiple databases? (i.e., per build configuration like a 'QA' version and a 'Production' version)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create multiple configuration files by opening Properties window for Database project
and adding new `Deployment configuration file`.

You can specify different files for each Configuration, ie. Debug can deploy to localhost, and Release to test environment.

Comment: -Thanks. After I add a new Deployment Configuration File, I don't see where you enter the 'named instance' (such as Localhost or wherever)

Comment: Nevermind, I found it. For anyone else who is interested, it's the 'Target Connection' under the 'Deploy' tab of the Database project properties. Thanks Jackub!